# Json formatting error message when making GET HTTP Call

Tags: c#, arrays, json, rest, get

i'm trying to return a list of users from our software and format the names and email addresses of these users into a list so can compare this to other lists and determine what is more accurate. i'm making the request using the code below.

Question: How do I format my code to accept a json array as the error message states?

```
public void MakeCall()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(_urlParameters).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<WorkfrontDataObjects>>().Result;

        foreach (var workfrontData in dataObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", workfrontData.Email);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}


public class WorkfrontDataObjects
{
    public string[] Email { get; set; }

    public string[] Name { get; set; }

    public WorkfrontDataObjects()
    {

    }
}
```

Error Message:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ManageWorkfrontADUserDistros.WorkfrontDataObjects]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'data', line 1, position 8.

UPDATE, adding json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": "000000000000000000000000000000",
            "name": "name",
            "objCode": "USER",
            "emailAddr": "email"
        },
        {
            "ID": "000000000000000000000000000000",
            "name": "name",
            "objCode": "USER",
            "emailAddr": "email"
        },
```

2500 of whats above with obviously real data

Comment: Thank you for the edit @douvillema. Can you please tell me what command i need to enter to in case the error message in the yellow box? i've never been able to do that?

Comment: Actually, the error says the opposite.  You are apparently receiving a single JSON object (denoted by curly braces `{}`), but you are trying to deserialize it into an `IEnumerable<WorkfrontDataObjects>`.  Can you edit your question to include the actual JSON you are receiving?  It is difficult to advise you how to fix your code without being able to see what data you are working with.

Comment: @BrianRogers i added a sample of the expected json i should be getting back. I added two of the items but their are 2500 in total.

Comment: Have you tried serialising dropping some sample data into your object to see what JSON it produces, they should match in terms of JSON construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your JSON, your model needs to look like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Item> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("objCode")]
    public string ObjCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("emailAddr")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

You can rename the classes and properties to suit your needs without affecting the deserialization, as long as the names in the `[JsonProperty]` attributes match the JSON.

Then you should be able to receive the data like this:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var rootObject = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>().Result;

    foreach (var item in rootObject.Data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Email);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like this was dead on with what i needed to get done. i didn't know i had to setup the json to included the data object if there was nothing in it. Thank you for teaching me this!

Answer (score 0):

Your `string[]` should be `string` in WorkfrontDataObjects and email should be emailAddr